# Menu capability in Wordpress

Tags: capabilities, add-submenu-page

Is it possible to specify two usergroups (e.g. admins and editors) into the admin menu capability field ? I tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
add_submenu_page(
     'my-top-level-handle',
     'Page title',
     'Sub-menu title',
      array('administrator', 'editor'),
     'my-submenu-handle',
     'my_magic_function'
);
```

error message:

Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\capabilities.php on line 712

Comment: You're not suppose to pass a role(or roles) to the **capability** parameter. Give it a capability only editors(or above) have and the page will be available to both admins and editors.

Comment: @t31os Please stop posting your answers into comments or I cannot give you the rep that you deserve. :)

Comment: @toscho - Sometimes i just intend to comment and answer without even realising, i'm just too impatient to think before i click that button... sorry.. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Capability parameter of [add_submenu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) function can only take a single capability, 
so if you are using the built in roles you can [select a capability fro the long list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) that both administrators and editors have any of these 
(use any of these freely):

- moderate_comments
- manage_categories
- manage_links
- unfiltered_html
- edit_others_posts
- edit_pages
- edit_others_pages
- edit_published_pages
- publish_pages
- delete_pages
- delete_others_pages
- delete_published_pages
- delete_others_posts
- delete_private_posts
- edit_private_posts
- read_private_posts
- delete_private_pages
- edit_private_pages
- read_private_pages

Answer (score 1):

As t31os said, you can use capabilities instead of roles there. One way to do this is to use core capabilities. (A more advanced method is to add a custom capability to the roles of your choice.) The default caps are in `wp-admin/includes/schema.php` in the functions called by `populate_roles()`.

If you are using standard roles/caps, you can specify only admins and editors by the cap `level_7` or `edit_others_posts` or several others.

Comment: `level` is deprecated for years. It may be dropped in the near future.