# How do i make a custom top level dashboard menu item available for all users?

Tags: menus, dashboard

I'm trying to add a top-level menu-item to all of my users their Wordpress dashboard.

With the code I'm using the menu item only show up for me, the admin.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'edit_page' );


function edit_page() {
    global $menu;
    $menu[500] = array( __('Edit page'), 'manage_options', admin_url( 'post.php?post=8&action=edit' ), '', 'open-if-no-js menu-top', '', 'dashicons-screenoptions' );
}
```

Tried several things like this:

```
if ( current_user_can('edit_files') ) {
    add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'admin_menu_wpse32975' );
}
```

But no luck.. so :

*How do i make a custom top level dashboard menu item available for all users?*

Comment: Possibly helpful to you - the issue is the manage_options capability is for admins  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13493/menu-capability-in-wordpress

Comment: Where did you get the obsolete `edit_files`? Please read the documentation before asking here

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Aravona I found a fix!

```
function give_user_manage_options() {
    $role_object = get_role( '$role' );
    $role_object->add_cap( 'manage_options');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'give_user_manage_options');
```

Comment: Make sure this does not give non admin users access to things suchs as plugins - you may just want to replace manage_options in your menu setup with a lower user setting.